# Como saber se há um elemento em um índice de List sem dar erro?

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, java-8

Estou tentando dar um `get()` nos índices de uma `ArrayList`, para que, se houver algo nessas posições, eu some esse valor com outra coisa. Só que se não existir esse índice, eu gostaria de adicioná-lo.

Porém, a IDE já dá "Index out of bounds" assim que eu dou um `get` num índice que não existe. Não poderia simplesmente retornar `null`? Ou algo assim?

A linha do erro é:

```
aColorCount = byColorCount.get(ar[x]);
```

O trecho de código:

```
 static int sockMerchant(int n, int[] ar) {
        List<Integer> byColorCount = new ArrayList(100);
        int aColorCount = -1;
        for(int x=0; x<ar.length; x++){
//Eu ia fazer um if abaixo, pra ver se o elemento existe, mas só da dar get já estoura a lista
           aColorCount = byColorCount.get(ar[x]);

           byColorCount.add(ar[x], aColorCount++);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O construtor `new ArrayList(100)` [só está setando a capacidade inicial para 100](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-), mas a lista em si não possuirá nenhum elemento. Basta ver que o código abaixo imprime `0`:

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList(100).size()); // 0
```

Ou seja, a [lista criada é vazia](https://ideone.com/5kJDQ0): qualquer acesso a qualquer índice com `get` - inclusive `get(0)` - vai dar erro, já que a lista não possui nenhum elemento.

Esse `100` é somente a capacidade inicial. Basicamente, quando a lista é criada, internamente é pré-alocada uma determinada quantidade de itens (nesse caso, 100). Quer dizer que esta lista tem 100 espaços disponíveis para guardar elementos. Conforme você vai adicionando elementos na lista, esses espaços vão sendo usados. Quando é verificado que não há mais espaço, a lista aloca mais capacidade automaticamente ([leia a documentação para mais detalhes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)).

No seu caso não está muito claro o que pretende. Está criando uma lista sem nada e quer verificar se tem algo nela (mas nunca vai ter, porque ela é vazia).

Se quer iniciar a lista com 100 elementos, pode usar [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-):

```
List<Integer> byColorCount = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(100, null));
```

Assim, a lista terá 100 elementos, e todos eles serão `null`. Ou pode usar `Collections.nCopies(100, 0)` para que todos sejam zero, por exemplo (ou faça o bom e velho `for` para adicionar 100 elementos).

Em seguida, basta verificar se `ar[x]` não é maior que a quantidade de elementos do array, e se o valor é `null`:

```
List<Integer> byColorCount = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(100, null));

for (int x = 0; x < ar.length; x++) {
    if (ar[x] >= 0 && ar[x] < byColorCount.size()) {
        // verifica se byColorCount.get(ar[x]) não é null
        if (byColorCount.get(ar[x]) != null) {
            // faz o que quiser com byColorCount.get(ar[x])
        } else {
            // elemento é nulo, setar para outro valor
            byColorCount.set(ar[x], x);
        }
    }
}
```

Não está claro porque você está usando `ar[x]` como o índice, e como esse array pode ter qualquer valor, é melhor verificar antes se esse valor não é maior que a quantidade de elementos da lista - e também se não é negativo (o primeiro `if`). Assim você evita o `IndexOutOfboundsException`.

Em seguida, basta verificar se o elemento é nulo ou não e tomar as ações de acordo com cada caso.

Comment: O seu primeiro exemplo resolve o que eu preciso. Mas o que eu não entendi ainda é o seguinte: se eu usar uma LinkedList por exemplo, posso inserir elementos em índices esparsos? E quero verificar se um determinado índice esparso existe na lista. Tem como? Talvez try catch funcione, o que acha?

Comment: @LucasPletsch `LinkedList` é uma lista também, e se criar uma com x elementos e tentar acessar o x + 1, vai dar erro. Se quer elementos esparsos, talvez a melhor forma seja emular isso com um `Map`.